# Joining 6 tables without duplicates

Tags: mysql, database, join

I've tried to get data from 6 different tables with joins, but every time there are showing multi duplicates. I a read a lot about that, but after many experiments I did not come to answer. Hope someone will know the answer. Here are my tables and one of my experiments.

1. Users -id, email
2. Teachers - id, user_id, name, telephone
3. Teacher_class - id, class_id, teacher_id
4. Classes - id, class
5. Teacher_Disipline - id, discipline_id, teacher_id
6. Disciplines - id,
   discipline

I am trying to get this view:

```
Name                 Email               Telephone         Classes     Disciplines
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  First name       first@gmail.com      2559857544         Va,VB,VIa   Html,CSS
```

Instead my table looks like this:

```
Name                 Email               Telephone         Classes     Disciplines
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  First name       first@gmail.com      2559857544           Va          Html
  First name       first@gmail.com      2559857544           Vb          Html
  First name       first@gmail.com      2559857544           VIa         Html
  First name       first@gmail.com      2559857544           Va          CSS
  First name       first@gmail.com      2559857544           Vb          CSS
  First name       first@gmail.com      2559857544           VIa         CSS
```

Here is my code

```
$sql_users_students = "SELECT * FROM users 
INNER JOIN teachers ON users.id = teachers.user_id
INNER JOIN teacher_class ON teachers.user_id = teacher_class.teacher_id
INNER JOIN classes ON teacher_class.class_id = classes.id
LEFT JOIN teacher_discipline ON teachers.user_id = teacher_discipline.teacher_id
left JOIN disciplines ON teacher_discipline.discipline_id = disciplines.id";

 <tbody>
 <?php foreach($teachers as $key => $info){
  echo "<tr><td>".$info["name"]."</td><td>".$info["email"]."</td><td>".$info["telephone"]."</td><td>".$info["class"]."</td><td>".$info["discipline"]."</td></td><td><a href=''php/delete_student.php''>Изтриване</a></td></tr>";} ?>                 
  </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Comment: Consider group_concat.

Comment: If you never use GROUP_CONCAT, you'll be just fine - especially in the context of application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To join these values together by using `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT()`, as in:

```
SELECT 
  name,
  email,
  telephone,
  group_concat(distinct classes) as classes,
  group_concat(distinct disciplines) as disciplines
FROM users 
INNER JOIN teachers ON users.id = teachers.user_id
INNER JOIN teacher_class ON teachers.user_id = teacher_class.teacher_id
INNER JOIN classes ON teacher_class.class_id = classes.id
LEFT JOIN teacher_discipline ON teachers.user_id = teacher_discipline.teacher_id
left JOIN disciplines ON teacher_discipline.discipline_id = disciplines.id
group by name, email, telephone
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use group_concat(function),

```
SELECT users.name, users.email, teachers.telephone, 
group_concat(classes.class ', ') as classes, group_concat(disciplines.discipline ', ') 
as disciplines 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN teachers ON users.id = teachers.user_id
INNER JOIN teacher_class ON teachers.user_id = teacher_class.teacher_id
INNER JOIN classes ON teacher_class.class_id = classes.id
LEFT JOIN teacher_discipline ON teachers.user_id = teacher_discipline.teacher_id
left JOIN disciplines ON teacher_discipline.discipline_id = disciplines.id";
```